# Getting erorr 404 while replaying

Tags: jmeter

I recorded a script through chrome extension. but when I replay the script
got error ,I checked in view result tree and expand the sampler there are plenty of files in which a .js file is throwing 404 error.

How can I remove this file(Sample)

Help Please!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVwyb.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can turn off failures reporting for embedded resources by adding the next line to *user.properties* file (lives under /bin folder of your JMeter installation)

```
httpsampler.ignore_failed_embedded_resources=true
```

JMeter restart will be required to pick the property up.

You can also pass this property via `-J` command-line argument like:

```
jmeter -Jhttpsampler.ignore_failed_embedded_resources=true .....
```

See [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) for more information on different JMeter properties types and ways of setting and overriding them